# PHP how to get value from array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array $result

```
array(2) {
  ["Smiley TV"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Speed"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "9510"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "33775"
    }
    ["Turbo"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2427"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "19696"
    }
  }
  ["Victory Media"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Speed"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "4144"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "80445"
    }
  }
}
```

How with foreach i can get values. For example in the "Smyley TV" how i can result "Speed".
Also please write how i can get all data one by one. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you do not know how to access array elements... A hint: `$myArray["Victory Media"]["Speed"][0]`...

Comment: I hope this will show you idea. Also check out PHP manual [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

foreach($array as $key => $item){ if($key == 'Smiley TV'){ $item['speed];} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch this way

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
   echo $array['smyley TV'];
}
```